# What is the equivalent of survey::svymean(~interaction()) using the srvyr package?

Tags: r, survey

I need some help analyzing survey data.

Here is my code.
Data prep

```
library(survey)
library(srvyr)
data(api)

dclus2 <- apiclus1 %>%
  as_survey_design(dnum, weights = pw, fpc = fpc)
```

These two codes give me the same result.

One using the package survey

```
#Code
survey::svymean(~awards, dclus2)

#Results
             mean    SE
awardsNo  0.28962 0.033
awardsYes 0.71038 0.033
```

One using the package srvyr

```
#Code
srvyr::dclus2%>%
       group_by(awards)%>%
       summarise(m=survey_mean())

#Results
awards    m            m_se
No     0.2896175    0.0330183       
Yes    0.7103825    0.0330183
```

I would like to get the survey mean of by the variable "awards" subset by the variable "stype" with levels No and Yes.

In the survey package, interaction is used
eg.`svymean(~interaction(awards,stype), dclus2)` How do I get the same result using the srvyr package?

Thank you for your help

How do get the result below using the package srvyr?

```
#Code
svymean(~interaction(awards,stype), dclus2)

#Results
                                    mean     SE
interaction(awards, stype)No.E  0.180328 0.0250
interaction(awards, stype)Yes.E 0.606557 0.0428
interaction(awards, stype)No.H  0.043716 0.0179
interaction(awards, stype)Yes.H 0.032787 0.0168
interaction(awards, stype)No.M  0.065574 0.0230
interaction(awards, stype)Yes.M 0.071038 0.0203
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply imitate the recommended behavior for `survey`: create a new variable formed by concatenating distinct values of each of the component variables. That's all that the `interaction()` function is doing for `svymean()`.

```r
library(survey)
library(srvyr)

data(api)

# Set up design object
dclus2 <- apiclus1 %>%
  as_survey_design(dnum, weights = pw, fpc = fpc)

# Create 'interaction' variable
dclus2 %>%
  mutate(awards_stype = paste(awards, stype, sep = " - ")) %>%
  group_by(awards_stype) %>%
  summarize(
    prop = survey_mean()
  )
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   awards_stype   prop prop_se
#>   <chr>         <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 No - E       0.180   0.0250
#> 2 No - H       0.0437  0.0179
#> 3 No - M       0.0656  0.0230
#> 4 Yes - E      0.607   0.0428
#> 5 Yes - H      0.0328  0.0168
#> 6 Yes - M      0.0710  0.0203
```

To get the various component variables split back into separate columns, you can use the `separate()` function from the `tidyr` package.

```r
# Separate the columns afterwards
dclus2 %>%
  mutate(awards_stype = paste(awards, stype, sep = " - ")) %>%
  group_by(awards_stype) %>%
  summarize(
    prop = survey_mean()
  ) %>%
  tidyr::separate(col = "awards_stype",
                  into = c("awards", "stype"),
                  sep = " - ")
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>   awards stype   prop prop_se
#>   <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 No     E     0.180   0.0250
#> 2 No     H     0.0437  0.0179
#> 3 No     M     0.0656  0.0230
#> 4 Yes    E     0.607   0.0428
#> 5 Yes    H     0.0328  0.0168
#> 6 Yes    M     0.0710  0.0203
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: As a warning, inside the `paste()` and `separate()` functions, you might want to carefully choose a delimiter so that the delimiter doesn't appear in the text of any component variables. For example, if one of the values of a variable was "1 - Strongly disagree", then using a delimiter of " - " will cause problems.

Comment: Do you have an idea about how to obtain the row percentages of awards by stype using the srvyr package?

I used the survey package and it worked.

`library(survey)`
`data(api)`

`dclus2 <- apiclus1 %>%`
  `as_survey_design(dnum, weights = pw, fpc = fpc)`
`svyby(~awards, by=~stype,dclus2,svymean)`

Results showing row percentages

     stype   awardsNo      awardsYes

E E 0.2291667 0.7708333 
H H 0.5714286 0.4285714 
M M 0.4800000 0.5200000

How do I create this result above using the srvyr package?

Comment: Solved the question, yay

library(survey)
library(srvyr)
data(api)

dclus2 <- apiclus1 %>%
  as_survey_design(dnum, weights = pw, fpc = fpc)

dclus2%>%
  group_by(stype,awards)%>%
  summarise(m=round(survey_mean(),4)*100)